# Bootstrap Tabs do not work when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap for a website and using the tab functionality that it brings. I looked at the documentation and I believe that I am doing everything right.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="works" class="ptb-80 bb-1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2>How It Works?</h2>
      <div class="seperator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbable full-width-tabs">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-one">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Build Your Own</span><br>Application Pool</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-two">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Search for</span><br>Uploaded Files</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-three">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Keep The Files</span><br>Safe and Secure</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-four">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Share with</span><br>Your Own Friends</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#tab-one" data-toggle="tab" class="primary-bg">
            <i>1</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Build Your Own</span><br>Application Pool</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-two" data-toggle="tab" class="secondary-bg">
            <i>2</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Search for</span><br>Uploaded Files</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-three" data-toggle="tab" class="primary-bg">
            <i>3</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Keep The Files</span><br>Safe and Secure</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-four" data-toggle="tab" class="secondary-bg">
            <i>4</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Share with</span><br>Your Own Friends</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /tabbable -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->
</section>
<!-- End Section -->
```

I have been unable to find what is wrong with the tabs, I have not changed anything in the javascript files so it should work. I am not sure how I include bootstrap in to the code snippet thing  so I am using bootstrap v3.3.6.

From other posts I have looked at I do not see anything that is out of place.

Comment: just added the bootstrap for you

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are missing the `bootstrap.js` file, add it and it works. See below demo of your code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section id="works" class="ptb-80 bb-1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2>How It Works?</h2>
      <div class="seperator"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tabbable full-width-tabs">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-one">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Build Your Own</span><br>Application Pool</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-two">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Search for</span><br>Uploaded Files</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-three">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Keep The Files</span><br>Safe and Secure</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-four">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
              <img src="images/step-1.png" class="img-responsive" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12 ptb-40">
              <div class="main-content p-20">
                <h3><span>Share with</span><br>Your Own Friends</h3>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean mattis lectus vitae lobortis dapibus. Aliquam nunc nunc, eleifend a sodales vel, tempor sit amet mi. Sed quis orci at orci elementum hendrerit. Nulla libero arcu, dapibus ut nunc vel, luctus
                  fringilla mi. Nullam in fermentum ipsum. Mauris iaculis dui hendrerit, mattis erat id, porttitor ipsum.
                </p>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="list">
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</li>
                      <li><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right primary-color"></i>Duis lacinia dolor quis</li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#tab-one" data-toggle="tab" class="primary-bg">
            <i>1</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Build Your Own</span><br>Application Pool</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-two" data-toggle="tab" class="secondary-bg">
            <i>2</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Search for</span><br>Uploaded Files</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-three" data-toggle="tab" class="primary-bg">
            <i>3</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Keep The Files</span><br>Safe and Secure</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#tab-four" data-toggle="tab" class="secondary-bg">
            <i>4</i>
            <h5 class="heading-alt"><span>Share with</span><br>Your Own Friends</h5>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
    <!-- /tabbable -->
  </div>
  <!-- End Container -->
</section>
<!-- End Section -->
```

Comment: That file is at the bottom of my body tag in my page.

Comment: is it workin in your case or not just make sure it is included after jquery ?

Comment: do select the correct answer so that other getting the same problem get benefit

Comment: The error was thae the previous developer put this in the css pointer-events: none;  and some hidden js that I did not see.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation all the tab examples i see assign a role to the anchor tag in the tab list: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs

```html
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Maybe try adding roles? I think the role effect how the item is supposed to act, so instead of acting like an anchor link, it should act like a tab.

Comment: he was just missing the js file for bootstrap

Comment: ah, he said the js was all working, thought it was in the head somewhere

Comment: hehe , happens most of the time.

Comment: what does role="tabpanel1" do. Why arent they unique values